# Set feature before selected element in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a some features that must be always in front of any other feature, the problem is that when I draw new feature or select current one it overlaps all other features.
Is there a way I can set some features or a layer to be always on top of everything ?

Comment: For features on the same layer use zIndex in the style settings for each feature e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742681/is-there-anyway-to-specify-z-order-of-feature-on-single-layer (and copy to their "selected" style in ol.interaction.Select). For features on separate layers use the zIndex option in the layer constructor or use layer.setZIndex().

Comment: I already use zIndex for layers and it working great, but when a feature is selected it always get on top even if I set its zIndex or its layer zIndex.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are not specifying zIndex in the selected style for the interaction.  In this code sample for hover on features in certain layers I set the selected style to be the same as the normal unselected style for the layer and only change the cursor

```
var interStyle;

function interFilter(feature, layer) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layerTypes.length; i++) {
        if (layer && layer.get("jsonName") && layer.get("jsonName").slice(-7) == layerTypes[i] + ".json") {
            interStyle = layer.getStyle();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var interHover = new ol.interaction.Select({ condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
                                             style: function(feature) { return interStyle; },
                                             filter: interFilter });

interHover.on( "select",
               function(event) { rowMap.getViewport().style.cursor = event.selected.length > 0 ? "pointer" : "";
                                 // optional callback to inform the calling page the mouse is over/off a feature
                                 if (options.setMouseOver) { options.setMouseOver(event.selected.length > 0); } }
);
```

The purple line remains below the green line at all times:

[image]

However if I comment out the style setting

```
var interHover = new ol.interaction.Select({ condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
                                             // style: function(feature) { return interStyle; },
                                             filter: interFilter });
```

When hovering over the purple line it takes OpenLayers default blue selected style and appears above the green line

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed examples. I've managed to change the style of the selected layer but not the zIndex. The selected feature is still over all elements even if the zIndex is specified lower. Here is code example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxjOKb/

Comment: Unfortunately I have now been able to reproduce the issue with my code (which uses separate layers for the two features).  It's more apparent with a click interaction but in my case it's not important.  It seems it was raised with the OpenLayers team last year but there has been no fix yet, just two suggested workarounds https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/7365

Comment: Here's an old question with some still applicable fiddle examples which keep hightlighted features in the background by avoiding select interactions https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156270/openlayers-3-hover-effect-below-top-layer-with-labels

Comment: Unfortunately non of those is a real solution, will try to work something out but it seems that there is nothing I can do at the moment. Thanks for the help!